# error log on npm start

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know there is a lot of questions about that but I can't resolve it by myself, because I'm not sure about what the error log talks about.

Here it is:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.5.1
3 info using node@v0.12.1
4 verbose node symlink C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe
5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
6 info prestart essai_mongo@0.0.0
7 info start essai_mongo@0.0.0
8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 info essai_mongo@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script
10 verbose stack Error: essai_mongo@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
10 verbose stack Exit status 1
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:213:16)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:14:12)
10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1008:16)
10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1080:5)
11 verbose pkgid essai_mongo@0.0.0
12 verbose cwd C:\Users\***\essai_mongo
13 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
14 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
15 error node v0.12.1
16 error npm  v2.5.1
17 error code ELIFECYCLE
18 error essai_mongo@0.0.0 start: `node ./bin/www`
18 error Exit status 1
19 error Failed at the essai_mongo@0.0.0 start script 'node ./bin/www'.
19 error This is most likely a problem with the essai_mongo package,
19 error not with npm itself.
19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
19 error     node ./bin/www
19 error You can get their info via:
19 error     npm owner ls essai_mongo
19 error There is likely additional logging output above.
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Also, here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "essai_mongo",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0",
     "mongoose": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

I don't know if i't about administratot rights, start path on package.json  (I've tried `C:\Users\***\essai_mongo\bin\www`), environment variable,.. Any help would be appreciate

Comment: Have you done `Tell the author that this fails on your system`?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm not sur this can help, I've had gyp problem but it's fixed now

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: @Venom I'm sorry I don't remember. Usually I post the solution if I find it (it seems to be the case). So if I didn't post, that means that was a stupid error from myself